# DevExpress XPF GridControl: event after edit value changed?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, devexpress

I am using a `DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.GridControl` , where one of the columns is bound to a property with getter and setter, and is therefore editable.

The class the grid is bound to cannot be modified.

I'd like to have an event fired when the value of that column is edited, so to trigger some operations. With the WinForms version, there was an event `RepositoryItem.EditValueChanged` event. The XPF version of GridControl replaced `RepositoryItem` with `BaseEditSettings`, yet I couldn't find an equivalent to the `EditValueChanged` event.

Comment: If you are using an `ObervableCollection` - you could use the `PropertyChanged` event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the [TableView.CellValueChanged](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridGridViewBase_CellValueChangedtopic) event should suits your needs.

Related help-article: [Obtaining and Setting Cell Values](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6150)